"run-down" versus "rundown"
In The Complete Poems of Anna Akhmatova by Judith Hemschemeyer, we read:

In this everyday gray dress,
On rundown heels...

I thought that "rundown" was a substantive and "run-down" an adjective. Nevertheless, here "rundown" is an adjective. I couldn't find a dictionary that allows "rundown" as an adjective. Is it the case that "rundown" can be an adjective too or is it a typo here? Is there a difference between American English and British English in this regard?

I'd guess the poet (or translator) thinks it looks nicer without the hyphen; poets don't have to follow the same spelling rules as New York Times journalists with their big stylebook.

Whatever the translator says. There is no rule. rundown is not a noun except in to give someone a rundown, which is basically colloquial.

Which dictionaries have you looked in?

@EdwinAshworth  a) oed.com/search/dictionary/?scope=Entries&q=run-down and b) dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rundown

Please show such information in the question, then others won't repeat the fruitless searches, and will look elsewhere. // Dictionaries differ in the number of headwords they include, the number of senses they define, and the number of spelling variations they license.

Personal observation: many people seem afraid of hyphens.  AISI, in many cases British English prefers to use two separate words and American English tends to combine them into one word, when hyphenating them would be clearer and more accurate.  (Random example: ‘the best-known author’ — ‘bestknown’ is awkward, and ‘best known author’ has a different meaning.)

American Heritage Dictionary has an example of "rundown" as an adjective without the hyphen:

b. Dirty and dilapidated: rundown housing projects.

AHD run-down
So, there is a dictionary example.

The first dictionary in the Merriam-Webster Collegiate Dictionary series to contain an entry for either run-down or rundown, was the fifth edition (1936), which includes this item:

run-down, adj. a Dilapidated. b Exhausted; worn out. c Of a watch or clock, stopped for want of winding.

The seventh edition (1963) of the Collegiate Dictionary revised the wording of the entry for the adjective run-down and introduced an entry for the noun rundown:

run-down adj 1 : being in poor repair : DILAPIDATED 2 : worn out : EXHAUSTED 3 : completely unwound
rundown n : an item-by-item report : SUMMARY

Even today, Merriam-Webster Online hews to the 1963 split in orthography between run-down for the adjective and rundown for the noun, although it does now acknowledge (and has acknowledged since the eighth edition of the Collegiate Dictionary) the baseball sense of rundown—a term that appears to have been used in that sport since at least 1908:

rundown noun 1 : an item-by-item report or review : summary 2 : a play in baseball in which a base runner who is caught off base is chased by two or more opposing players who throw the ball from one to another in an attempt to tag the runner out
run-down adjective 1 : being in poor repair : dilapidated 2 : worn-out, exhausted 3 : completely unwound

But as Jack O'Flaherty's answer points out, not all dictionaries are as slow to adapt to real-world closure of some previously hyphenated terms as Merriam-Webster seems to be. Thus, The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, fifth edition (2011) indicates that both rundown and run-down are in widespread use as spellings for the adjective, although AHDEL indicates its preference for the closed-up form:

rundown n. 1. A point-by-point summary. 2. Baseball A play in which a runner is trapped between bases and is pursued by fielders attempting to make the tag. | adj. also run-down 1a. In poor physical condition; weak or exhausted. b. Dirty and dilapidated: rundown housing projects. 2. Unwound and not running: a run-down watch.

The phenomenon of dropping hyphens from compound adjectives and closing them up as a single word is by no means a recent innovation. As a case in point, consider widespread (which happens to appear in my answer two paragraphs above this one). In the 1847 edition of Merriam-Webster's An American Dictionary of the English Language, the entry for the adjective is given exclusively as wide-spread; but in [Merriam-]Webster's International Dictionary (1890), the hyphen is gone and the adjective is closed up as widespread, without any acknowledgment that wide-spread might remain an acceptable variant spelling.
I expect instances of rundown as an adjective to become increasingly common as time goes on, both because there is a natural tendency for many compound adjectives to lose their hyphens as they become more and more familiar as expressions of consistent, readily definable ideas and because the single-word noun form rundown has been contributing to a visual normalization of that character string for at least sixty years.


I thought that "rundown" was a substantive and "run-down" an adjective.

There is not the slightest shred of truth in this: "run down" can be found as run-down and rundown as a noun and an adjective:
OED

rundown (n.)
The action or an act of running down or being run down in some way; spec. a gradual and sustained reduction in the size or scope of an
organization, enterprise, or activity.
1890 This rapid run-down of mechanism, comparable to the rupture of
the mainspring of a watch, renders it impossible in most cases to
distinguish any sequence in the resulting spasms. W. B. Lewis,
Text-book Mental Dis. 223
1978 They produced a report which could lead to an even swifter and
more drastic rundown in the industry than has been planned. Daily
Mirror 12 January 2/2
2000 A combination of deer fencing and lack of predator control is
increasing capercaillie and black grouse run-down in the Scottish
Highlands. Country Illustr. April 34

Adj

2008 She'd woken him at five o'clock, calling out from her bedroom to
ask him to turn off her beeping, run-down mobile phone. J. Mansell,
Offer you can't Refuse (2009) xxxiii. 241
1977 She consulted her doctor complaining of feeling run down and ‘off
colour’ and wondering whether she was anaemic. S. Macintyre, Single &
Pregnant iv. 59
2007 An isolated street of run-down Victorian tenements by the side of
the motorway. E. Morrison, Swung (2008) i. 8


2019 It took nearly a half hour to reach the address for my new assignment.
It was a small rundown house out in the middle of nowhere. Goodnight
Mysteries Books 1-3 By Elise Sax


There is not the slightest shred of truth in this" : a) https://www.oed.com/search/dictionary/?scope=Entries&q=run-down
and b) https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rundown
let think that there is a shred of truth in this.

@Bruno - you will note that all of the quotes are from the OED except the final one. The point is that the general evolution of words starts with two separate words; these become hyphenated, and finally it is one word. However, many simply get stuck in all three positions and are all equally valid.

... moreover, even when a word does not get stuck, its evolution from separate words to compound word leaves behind a trail of historical usage that, as a practical matter, may be hard to distinguish from getting stuck.
